# Prove statement using formulas and then using a counting argument.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Prove the following statement first by using formulas and second by using a counting argument.
$$
\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{j} = \binom{n}{j}\binom{n-j}{k}
$$

Comment: You could at least do the factorial proof, to show some work on your part.

Comment: You will find help here if you show what you have tried and where you got stuck. We don't do your homework, we help you doing it yourself. Second, in order to format your formula, place two dollar signs before and after it.

Comment: Please visit [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and then read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking).  You'll first be led to a tour of the site, and then to the Help section on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counting argument. First, observe that the required equality may be reformulated as :

$$\binom n{n-k}\binom{n-k}j=\binom nj\binom{n-j}{n-j-k}$$

and even, with $p=n-k$ :

$$\binom np\binom pj=\binom nj\binom{n-j}{p-j}\tag{1}$$

Now consider a set of cardinal $n$, and count the numbers of ways we can form a pair of subsets $(A,B)$ with $card(A)=p$, $card(B)=j$ and $B\subset A$. This number is given by the LHS of $(1)$.

But it can also be viewed as the number of ways we can choose first $B$ and *then* complete this choice with $p-j$ elements outside of $B$. This leads to the RHS.

Comment: Downvote is ok, but a comment would make more sense and would be fairplay.